# Is it possible to append a block to the footer in admin dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template, dashboard

I'm trying to append a block to the footer but only on the dashboard page i.e.

```
<footer>
[New Template]
[Core Content]
</footer>
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried a layout file with the following but nothing is displayed:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_dashboard_index>
        <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
            <label>New Reference</label>
        </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="newreference">
        <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="stats.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_dashboard_index>
</layout>
```

**Do I have the path or reference name wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to append a block to the footer in admin dashboard. For that you have to simply override a default.xml file from below path :

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
```

After that you can simply made changes with this section :

```
       <container name="legal" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-legal">
            <container name="legal.copyright" htmlTag="p" htmlClass="copyright col-m-6">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Copyright" name="copyright" as="copyright" />
            </container>
            <container name="legal.system" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-legal-system col-m-6">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Footer" name="version" as="version" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report" as="report" template="Magento_Backend::page/report.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="bugreport_url" xsi:type="string">https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </container>
```